# Opengl "Cannot find bounds of current function"

Tags: c++, opengl, netbeans, cmake, msys

Every time I step over any opengl function in debug mode (I use msys) gdb throws at me "Cannot find bounds of current function". This results in debug cursor jumping out of the function to it's call. This behavior is only observed when I step over opengl function call. It doesn't occur if I'm stepping over non-opengl functions (even if they contain some of ogl api call) or break before or after gl.

I use MSYS and GLAD. (also GLM but I believe this one is irrelevant).
Here's the example of code that would give such error:

```
glBindVertexArray(_glVAO_Id); 
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

All is working, triangles being drawn correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i fount the problem. When generating glad files at https://glad.dav1d.de I picked C/C++ as language. Turns out this dropdown has options C/C++ Debug. Regenerating files and cleaning build folder helped alleviate the problem.